# WebDriver simulate touch events in Desktop Browser

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, touch-event

I'm trying to simulate some touch events like swap, tap in web-based application using Chrome and Firefox browsers. I've tried to simulate touch events with [Actions](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions), [Hummber.js](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/), "[Yahoo](http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.8.1/build/yui/)" lib(YUI) but none of them works for me.

What is the best way to simulate touch events with webdriver in desktop browsers?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [phantom limb](http://viewinglens.com/phantom-limb/) which transforms mouse events to touch events. It worked for me. I thing the best way to simulate touch events in Chrome is to use built-in emulations mechanism. Like in [this](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation?hl=ru) article. Unfortunately I can't find the way to turn on this feature by webdriver. Found the Chrome options like "enable-touch-events", "touch-events" and etc. But it didn't worked.

UP: Chrome Driver allows to emulate chrome browser on mobile device. Read this [article](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation).

Answer (score 0):

With jQueryMobile it is quite simple, I execute some Javascript which trigger the corresponding touch events from jQueryMobile.

```java
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.jQuery('#myId').trigger('swiperight')");
```

Maybe that helps.