# Swipe ng-repeat based carousel component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have got **browser** carousel component based on **ng-repeat**. The carousel can load partial html file and slice it over `<li>` elements.

I would like to be able to swipe carousel using protractor/webdriverjs in browser.

I have tried mouseDown(), mouseMove(), mouseUp() actions:

```
ptor.actions()
    .mouseDown({x: 500, y: 250})
    .mouseMove({x: 50, y: 250})
    .mouseUp()
    .perform();
```

or

```
ptor.actions()
    .mouseDown(ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('ra-slice-1')))
    .mouseMove({x: 500, y: 250})
    .mouseUp()
    .perform();
```

I have also tried dragAndDrop but I have no container to drop into.

From the code perspective everything is ok (no errors), but the carousel won't swipe.

Please advise.

Comment: Sadly, not supported by webdriver in browsers. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479143/webdriver-simulate-touch-events-in-desktop-browser. You may be able to get around it by triggering a javascript event, as described in the answers there.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
You may provide it as answer so I will mark it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, not supported by webdriver in browsers. See [stackoverflow.com/questions/15479143/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479143/). You may be able to get around it by triggering a javascript event, as described in the answers there. [Moved from comment]